# Finding the probability that at least one unit is excellent when two units are drawn from a sample with replacement

Tags: probability

> A company possesses a number of products in which $45$ units of them are excellent, $35$ units are good and $20$ units are bad.  Two units are drawn with replacement.  Find the probability that at least one of them is excellent.

My turn:

The number of ways to choose one or two excellent units is $$35C1 +35C2$$
The total number of ways to choose one or two units is $$100C1 + 100C2$$
Then the probability = $$\frac{35C1 + 35C2 }{100C1 + 100C2}$$
Is the solution correct ?

Comment: Why do you use the number of combinations to choose one or two units , if two units are chosen (moreover with replacement, so that you have a binomial distribution) ?

Comment: We can use it to compute the number if ways to draw r things out of n things without ordering @Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that at least one is excellent can be found by subtracting the probability that neither unit is excellent from $1$.  Since $45$ of the $45 + 35 + 20 = 100$ units are excellent, so 
$$\Pr(\text{a unit is excellent}) = \frac{45}{100} = \frac{9}{20}$$
Thus,
$$\Pr(\text{a unit is not excellent}) = 1 - \frac{45}{100} = \frac{55}{100} = \frac{11}{20}$$
Since the units are drawn with replacement, the probability a unit is not excellent is the same for each draw.  Therefore, 
$$\Pr(\text{neither unit is excellent}) = \left(\frac{11}{20}\right)^2 = \frac{121}{400}$$
Hence, 
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\text{at least one unit is excellent}) & = 1 - \Pr(\text{neither unit is excellent})\\
& = 1 - \left(\frac{11}{20}\right)^2\\
& = 1 - \frac{121}{400}\\
& = \frac{279}{400}
\end{align*}

**What is wrong with your approach?**

We are selecting two units out of $100$ units *with replacement*.

The number 
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$
is the number of ways of selecting a subset of $k$ elements from a set with $n$ elements.  It is used when items are drawn *without replacement*.

Since the items are drawn with replacement, there are $100$ units that could be selected in the first draw and the same $100$ units could be selected in the second draw.  Therefore, our denominator is $100 \cdot 100$.

Also, the problem states that there are $45$ excellent units, not $35$.

Therefore, for each draw, there are $45$ ways we could select one of the excellent units and $55$ ways we select one of the units that is not excellent.

There are three possible favorable cases:

1. An excellent unit is drawn on both draws, which has probability $$\Pr(\text{both units are excellent}) = \frac{45}{100} \cdot \frac{45}{100} = \frac{9}{20} \cdot \frac{9}{20} = \frac{81}{400}$$
2. An excellent unit is selected in the first draw and a unit that is not excellent is selected in the second draw, which has probability $$\Pr(\text{only the first unit is excellent}) = \frac{45}{100} \cdot \frac{55}{100} = \frac{9}{20} \cdot \frac{11}{20} = \frac{99}{400}$$
3. A unit that is not excellent is selected in the first draw and a unit that is excellent is selected in the second draw, which has probability $$\Pr(\text{only the second unit is excellent}) = \frac{55}{100} \cdot \frac{45}{100} = \frac{11}{20} \cdot \frac{9}{20} = \frac{99}{400}$$

Since these three events are exhaustive and mutually exclusive, 
$$\Pr(\text{at least one unit is excellent}) = \frac{81}{400} + \frac{99}{400} + \frac{99}{400} = \frac{279}{400}$$
which agrees with the answer we obtained above.

**Using the binomial distribution**

Finally, let's follow up on Peter's comment.  Since items are drawn without replacement, the probability of drawing an excellent unit is the same for each draw, which allows us to use the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), which says that the probability of exactly $k$ successes in $n$ trials, each with probability $p$ of success, is
$$\Pr(X = k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1 - p)^{n - k}$$
where $p^k$ is the probability of $k$ successes, $(1 - p)^{n - k}$ is the probability of $n - k$ failures, and $\binom{n}{k}$ counts the number of ways those $p$ successes could occur in $n$ trials.

Since we want the probability of at least one success in two trials, each of which has probability of success 
$$p = \frac{45}{100} = \frac{9}{20}$$
we obtain
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\text{at least one unit is excellent}) & = \sum_{k = 1}^{2} \binom{2}{k}\left(\frac{9}{20}\right)^k\left(1 - \frac{9}{20}\right)^{2 - k}\\
& = \binom{2}{1}\left(\frac{9}{20}\right)\left(\frac{11}{20}\right) + \binom{2}{2}\left(\frac{9}{20}\right)^2\left(\frac{11}{20}\right)^0\\
& = \frac{198}{400} + \frac{81}{400}\\
& = \frac{279}{400}
\end{align*}
Alternatively,
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\text{at least one unit is excellent}) & = 1 - \Pr(\text{neither unit is excellent})\\
& = 1 - \Pr(X = 0)\\
& = 1 - \binom{2}{0}\left(\frac{9}{20}\right)^0\left(\frac{11}{20}\right)^2\\
& = 1 - \frac{121}{400}\\
& = \frac{279}{400}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

What is $C1, C2$?

It is just (probability of first excellent) + (probability first is not excellent) * (probability of second excellent). I.e.:

$$\frac{35}{100} + \left( 1 - \frac{35}{100} \right) \cdot \frac{35}{100} = \frac{231}{400}$$

Comment: "What is $C1$, $C2$?"  One of the popular ways of denoting a binomial coefficient denoting the number of ways of selecting a subset of $r$ objects from a set of $n$ is as $~_nC_r$.  I personally prefer $\binom{n}{r}$, but it is good to familiarize yourself with the many ways people denote something.

Comment: It is the combination coefficient @JMoravits

Comment: Never seen *that* notation. Sure, stuff like $C_k^n$ and others like ${}_n C_k$. At least $n$ is missing here.

Comment: You misread the question.  The problem says that $45$ units are excellent.  What you calculated is the probability that at least one unit is good.